# Meaning of "He jotted down the conceits of his idle hours."

Tags: meaning, sentence

I was looking for meaning of the word 'conceit' and I came across this use of the word 'conceit':-

> "He jotted down the conceits of his idle hours."

I found the statement to be quite interesting but I am having hard time understanding it. Can somebody please help?

Comment: If you got that quotation from the [dictionary here](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/conceit), then the definitions 2-6 should be all you need to understand it. If not, what is it that you don't get?

Comment: @Spratty What I understood as the meaning of the word 'conceit' is  'excessively favorable opinion of one's own ability', which I couldn't relate to, here.

Comment: @SrujanBarai, see Silenus' answer - it will give you a complete breakdown of the sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The meaning of this sentence is entirely compositional (that is, determined by the meaning of its parts).

***[jot](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/jot?q=jotted)*** means:

> Write (something) quickly

***[conceit](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/conceit)*** means:

> A fanciful notion

or, more generally, an idea.

***[idle](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/idle)*** means:

> (Of time) characterized by inaction or absence of significant activity

Thus, ***idle hours*** means something like "spare time", or "leisure time", or "time spent doing nothing (except maybe thinking)".

Thus, the sentence

> ***He jotted down the conceits of his idle hours.***

means

> ***He wrote down the ideas that he came up with in his spare time.***

Comment: Spoon-fed to perfection... :)